# Is a ground plane useful in this analog PCB scenario?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, dac, ground-plane

I'm planning to make a DAC amplifier circuit on a PCB, with a schematic similar to the following example:

[image]

The PCB will be composed of a one quad op-amp, some resistors, some caps, and connectors for power and signal outputs.

The DAC input will come from another PCB which is controlled by a microcontroller and will be wired to the PCB DAC amplifier I'm aiming for.

So the DAC amplifier PCB will be a separate PCB and it will have input pins, power pins  and output pins for the external world. There are no digital components, but its Vcc and Vee will be powered from a dual SMPS.

In this case do I need a ground plane on the PCB?

Comment: Well, you do need a ground connection.  Does it need to be a plane/pour?  That depends on your concerns.  What are your concerns (and design requirements)?

Comment: I dont have so much PCB design knowledge. Only done years ago last time. Now I will use KicAD. The only reason I asked this question. If ground plane is not necessary it would make it easier for me to omit it. DAC will drive some sensitive galvo mirrors(which have built in 6kHz filters) so the only concern is interference such as common mode noise ect.

Comment: I'd propose to you that you could potentially make this on a 2-layer pcb, even though you have split supplies.  You could make judicious use of polygon pours for your ground signals on the top and/or bottom layers.  Then mitigate external interference by using a metal enclosure, and proper cabling.  But it's unlikely that, with the information given, anyone here can fully appreciate the details that could cause that oppressive wave of sadness when something doesn't go as planned.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, with smart placement that circuit can be routed pretty much on one layer. Since you always pay for two layers, you get the ground plane for free, basically. No matter if you actually need it (hard to tell anyway).

Just try to route everything on the top layer and keep the ground plane on the bottom as solid as possible. If you really have to route on the bottom layer, keep the traces as short as possible.

Maybe the split supply will make things a bit tricky. But I would give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Not in and of itself.  LM324 is way too slow to care about EMI emissions  Susceptibility is another matter.

The question is what's outside the board.  Will the DAC board be noisy?  Or any boards it's connected to (presumably an MCU somewhere?)?  Will it be at some distance (so the connecting wires/cables are susceptible to ambient noise)?  Will the power be adequately filtered (does the SMPS meet EMI regulations?*)

Considering the board, in and of itself, exposed to a typical environment: the biggest hazards will be input RF rectification, and ESD.

LM324 is a bipolar op-amp of conventional (old!) design.  Its input stage is a PNP differential pair.  This means the input pins connect directly to P-N junctions on the chip -- diodes.  If RF is applied to the pins (in practical terms, for this chip, "RF" is roughly anything >10MHz), the diode rectifies RF, and its peak amplitude is stored in nearby node capacitance.  In other words: RF is AM-detected and turned into an input offset voltage in your circuit.

In an audio context, this is the typical result: 
[Cell Phone Interference Sound Effects All Sounds - All Sounds | YouTube](https://youtu.be/uPYyrS7fc7g?t=15) 
Any modulation on the RF goes right into your circuit!

As for ESD, the inputs and outputs are sensitive: for example, [TI's LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf) is rated at 250V HBM only.  (Shockingly, this is *considerably* less than most CMOS circuits are rated for; these aren't notorious for ESD damage so I have to wonder if this is just an extraordinarily conservative rating or what?!)

Both issues are easily solved by adding filtering and protection at the input and output, and a TVS diode on the supplies wouldn't be a bad idea either (which also protects against hot-plugging / inrush overvoltage, which can happen when the bypass cap(s) resonate with the supply inductance following a step change in voltage).

A typical method then would be RC input filtering, clamp diodes to the supply, and for the output, maybe just clamp diodes, and a series resistor wouldn't hurt, but obviously its value can only be so much without increasing output resistance (depends on loading; if the next circuit has a high input impedance, this won't matter much and a larger value might be used).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU3d6t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, input and output filtering/protection something like this.  Zeners should probably be TVS types proper; it's unlikely you'd need anything as big as an SMAJxx series part; these can be little SOT-23 or SOD-323 or etc. size types just fine.  Note that the clamp diodes (D3 and D4) will shunt the bulk of ESD, but leave some excess voltage (if Vcc/Vee is ±10V say, the peak clamping voltage may be 40V or so), which could still damage the amp; the series resistor reduces the peak current available, so the clamp diodes take the brunt of it.

You could also use bidirectional TVSs to GND, instead of the clamp diodes; mind these will have more capacitance, so will affect signal bandwidth.

It may be desirable to have a ferrite bead at the output (perhaps the input as well, in place of R1), to absorb RFI and dampen possible resonances on the cabling.  Filter capacitance may also be useful; while the output is more tolerant than the input, it nonetheless contains lots of PN junctions that can rectify RF.

Circuit layout will be just fine on a 2-layer board with ground fill (don't forget via stitching around most traces, especially by trace crossings, and most inside corners, peninsulas and islands left in the pours by the traces cutting across them).  Place the EMI components near the connectors, and preferably group the connectors along one side, or along the edges of the board, so that RFI and ESD can flow around the periphery of the board, between connectors, while the inner circuit is shielded by the ground pour around it.  (High frequencies flow with a skin effect, preferring to stay along the outside of an object.  Pouring and stitching the ground plane, and keeping connectors towards the edge, harnesses this.)

Whether any of these lengths are necessary in the present case, I don't know -- EMI is a holistic study, and the more information that can be provided about the overall system, the better!

Ideally, the whole system would be inside a metal box, with filtering or shielding for all external inputs/outputs (cabling).  Then the only noise within, is that which is specifically allowed in through those connections, or produced in the system itself.  Which basically means the SMPS(s), and whatever MCU stuff might be connected.  In that case, no filtering or protection might be needed, nor ground plane/pour on the PCB.  Usually, real designs fall somewhere between these extremes: naked boards in a plastic enclosure vs. fully shielded.

---

*Even if it meets regulations, beware: supplies are typically tested with the output wired to a resistor on short leads.  There may be noise at the output, with respect to ground (i.e., common mode), or at frequencies outside of what's tested (usually ripple is measured into a bypass network with 20MHz bandwidth).  The output may be noisier than you might expect, and connecting the output to long wires may fail radiated EMI, or connecting it to ground may return more noise up the mains input, making it fail (conducted) EMI.  This, among other reasons, is why EMI is almost always tested on complete equipment, even when components claim to pass.

Conversely, an SMPS module that does not pass regulations, very likely will be perceptibly noisy in an application, without filtering.

In short, having approvals is helpful, but not sufficient for passing EMI (or other metrics of interference, like noise within an audio system).

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I decided to use another quad-opamp which in applications mentioned as "DAC output amplifier". It is OP484FPZ. Here is the datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/op184_284_484.pdf Do I still need the clamp diodes in your diagram? (And in my case for the SMPS dual supply Vcc=+15V and Vee=-15V) And the DAC amplifier in question will be used for a staircase ramp input from another DAC. The period of each stair will be around 500us and each stair input increase is 2.5mV.

Comment: Nice pick, very expensive though. They don't give an ESD rating but they do say it contains clamp diodes with a 5mA input current limit.  So use external clamp diodes and design R3 to limit that current accordingly.

Comment: This my circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlHJU.png  Already big resistors at the input stages. Do you think I need clipping diodes?

Comment: To clarify, they're not for clipping signal levels. Again, whether you need them for ESD depends on the overall system.